Can we create a 'FLL' tag?
We all know that the FIRST lego league challenge announcement is happening soon, and we will definitely ask questions about it. I have noticed that there is no 'FLL' or 'FIRST' or'FIRST lego league' tag. 
Could someone please add these helpful tags?

I just added it

I've added fll to your question (although I fear that is "too localised") and a rough wiki entry based on their about page. I've also created a synonym first-lego-league which will point to it. Feel free to suggest edits for other suitable questions for more rep ;)
